# cannot get past TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined error in a expo js project

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Im trying to do a search for a expo instagram clone and after I added code that is supposed to display either the users or the profile of the searched user to the profile screen it has been giving either a TypeError: undefined is not a function or TypeError: undefined is not a function error.

this is the profile page code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { app } from '../auth/firebaseConfig';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, onSnapshot, doc, orderBy, query, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

function Profile(props) {
    const [userPost, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const { currentUser, posts } = props;
    
        if (props.route.params.uid === getAuth(app).currentUser.uid) {
            setUser(currentUser);
            setUserPosts(posts);
        } else {
            const auth = getAuth(app);
            const firestore = getFirestore(app);
            const userDocRef = doc(firestore, "users", props.route.params.uid);
            const userPostsQuery = query(
                collection(firestore, 'posts', props.route.params.uid, 'userPosts'),
                orderBy('creation', 'asc')
            );
    
            const userUnsubscribe = onSnapshot(userDocRef, (snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    setUser(snapshot.data());
                } else {
                    console.log("User does not exist");
                }
            }, (error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching user data: ", error);
            });
    
            const postsUnsubscribe = onSnapshot(userPostsQuery, (snapshot) => {
                let posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                });
                setUserPosts(posts);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching user posts: ', error);
            });
    
            return () => {
                userUnsubscribe();
                postsUnsubscribe();
            };
        }
    }, [props.route.params.uid, props.currentUser, props.posts]);
    
    
    const { currentUser, posts } = props;
    console.log({ currentUser, posts });
    if(user === null) {
        return <View/>
    }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.containerInfo}>
        <Text>{user.name}Profile</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
            <FlatList
                numColumns={3}
                horizontal={false}
                data={userPosts}
                renderItem={({item}) =>(
                    <View style={styles.containerImage}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={{uri: item.downloadURL}}
                    />
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 40
    },
    containerInfo: {
        margin: 20
    },
    containerGallery: {
        flex: 1
    },
    image:{
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1/1
    },
    containerImage: {
        flex: 1/3
    }
})
const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    posts: store.userState.posts
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

and this is the search code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../auth/firebaseConfig';

export default function Search( props ) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchUsers = async (search) => {
    if (search) {
      const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
      const q = query(usersRef, where('name', '>=', search));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      let usersData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });

      setUsers(usersData);
    } else {
      setUsers([]);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {uid: item.id})}>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search for users..."
        onChangeText={(text) => fetchUsers(text)}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have tried switching the useEffect hook and looking through dependencies tried everything chatgpt4 said.

here is the git: https://github.com/willy161/sportsmate